# Get all images with certain class

Tags: jquery

I'm not sure how to ask this question but here is my explanation:

```
$(".phone img")
```

I want something like this. How to set an animation only to the images in phone class. This doesn't work obviously. The animation cover the entire class.

Comment: There is really only 1 answer to this, which is best anyway, and that is below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you do in $(".phone img") is to call all img tags inside any tag that has a phone class.
In order to match all images that have phone class, then it should be:

```
$("img.phone")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give a class name or Id to the image tag. Something like this

```
<div class="phone">
<img class="img_1"/>
</div>
```

Then you can call it like

```
$('.phone .img_1').animate();
```

That should do it.